Is AMG supposed to work with discontinuous Galerkin discretizations?
As the question says, are algebraic multigrid methods well suited to be used as preconditioners for problems discretised with Discontinuous Galerkin methods (say $p=1$)?
I've always used AMG (actually, TrilinosML implementation) as a preconditioner for the solution of systems arising from continuous $P^1$ elements on elliptic problems.
Recently, I tried to apply it on very simple, two-dimensional, Laplace problems discretised with symmetric interior penalty method and smooth manufactured solutions, discretised with DG and the conjugate-gradient solver does not convergence within thousands of thousands of iterations. (For the record, I tried with a direct solver since the size is small and convergence tests using manufactured solutions are okay, so I would exclude plain bugs in the linear systems.)

My gut feeling is "yes", but now I'm curious what others say. You may want to state what kind of DG discretization you choose -- it needs to be a symmetric and positive definite one.

Thanks, I've edited the post.

Cursory lit search seems to indicate that there are some AMG methods designed for DG that work well but I have no idea how these line up with methods implemented in the big packages. This seems like it may contain some relevant info https://doi.org/10.1137/16M110455X

If you know FEniCS or deal.II, it shouldn't be very difficult to test this out in another software project in which it's easy to switch solvers and/or discretizations.

It should work. I used it multiple times throughout my education and in my thesis too. A colleague of mine (Yunhui He) even generalized multigrid methods to Hybridized Discontinuous Galerkin Methods. You can also look at my thesis where we successfully use AIR multigrid problem on HDG discretizations of advection-diffusion equations.
